# How to prepared statements with Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am trying to run a statement to create a database and a user, but it seems laravel continues to run weird queries. My code is as follows:

```
$res = DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `?`", array($databaseName));
$res2 = DB::statement("CREATE USER '?'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '?'", array($databaseName, $password));
return $res . " - " . $res2;
```

I would expect the database to be created and a "true" result, but the query still gives me a false response and no database is created. Trying to run a statement with the $databaseName variable inside the query in a "dirty way" works, so I think there's something wrong with prepared statements. Which would be the right way to do it?

Thank you! :)

Update:
I've managed to do it, but it seems there are still SQL-injection issues because I'm still not able to use prepared statements. The first solution I've found is the following one:

```
$res = DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `{$databaseName}`");
$res2 = DB::statement("CREATE USER '{$databaseName}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$password}'");
return $res . " - " . $res2;
```

Comment: I believe your bindings are automatically quoted so there might be a possibility that you just created the database `'db_name'` with the quotes around it.  Did that one get created?

Comment: Not in this case, but using variables (like \`?\`) you're right: they are quoted and the query generated causes the database name to be malformed.
Eg.:

    `DB::statement("CREATE USER '?'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '?'", array($databaseName, $databasePassword));`


Isn't there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I've found that works:

```
DB::connection('database')->statement("CREATE USER '{$mysqlDatabaseName}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{$mysqlUserPassword}'");
DB::connection('database')->statement("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `{$mysqlDatabaseName}`");
DB::connection('database')->statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `{$mysqlDatabaseName}`.* TO '{$mysqlDatabaseName}'@'%'");
```

However, before you run these queries, you must make sure you have no SQL-injection in your code.

Hope this will help somebody else! :)

Comment: It helped, i was like you, no way to make this work, tried without quotes, tried with named parameters (:id) ...etc Only your solution worked. Is it a bug ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way you are supposed to deal with it, but to be honest since it works i don't care about it anymore. Yeah, it's not a clean solution, but right now it's not a huge deal :)